# Getting error while closing scanner class

Tags: java

I am getting an error while close scanner in java:
the error is: **in cannot be resolved**

**here is the lines of code:**

```
System.out.println("Enter your number: ");
number = scan.nextInt();
in.close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add this line :

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Updated code :

```
 Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.println("Enter your number: ");
 int number = in.nextInt();
 in.close();
```

That's all.

Comment: Generally, if the source is `System.in`, then you shouldn't call `close()` on `in`, as it will also close the standard input.

Answer (score 1):

Please update your code to initialize the Scanner class using below -

```
try(Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {
     System.out.println("Enter your number: ");
     int number = in.nextInt(); 
}
```

Thats it !! The above code will work on Java8 only as we are using Java8 try with resource concepts. This will automatically takes care of closing the resource after the try block end is reached. No need to manually call the close method.